# Prevent use of unsupported JavaScript features in IE11 using ESLint?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, eslint

I have an existing ESLint configuration with "ecmaVersion" set to "5" that I want to modify to allow the use of **let** and **const** which are ES6 features. There are mostly* supported in Internet Explorer 11. However, I want to reject the use of any ES6 features that aren't supported in IE11, e.g. classes. How can I do that with ESLint?

I did find the *eslint-plugin-ie11* plug-in, but it only covers a few unsupported features.

*I would also like to block the use of let in loops, which is not supported in IE11.

Comment: Why not using TypeScript or Babel? You are probably looking at a wrong tool

Comment: I am looking into such options for the future, but this affects a fairly large project and I was hoping to find an incremental and short-term solution.

Comment: if your large project is not using the mentioned above technologies then it most likely is just based on many `*.js` files that are added to HTML code. Just rename all files to e.g. `*.src.js` and use ES6 there, then use e.g. Babel https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli to compile them to `*.js` files. Migration is done. 10 minutes to rename all files (with a bash script even 1) and 10 minutes to configure babel.

Answer (score 0):

you can add eslint rules to disallow pretty much any language feature you want using the [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule.

from [the eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax)

> this rule allows you to configure the syntax elements you want to restrict use of
> ...
> You may find the full list of AST node names you can use [on GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/espree/blob/master/lib/ast-node-types.js) and use [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) with the espree parser to see what type of nodes your code consists of.
> ...
> You can also specify [AST selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors) to restrict, allowing much more precise control over syntax patterns.
> ...
> This rule takes a list of strings, where each string is an AST selector
> ...
> [, or] objects, where the selector and an optional custom message are specified

so, for example, if you wanted to block usage of arrow functions, template literals, and `let`/`const` declarations in the left side of `for`...`in` and `for`...`of` loops,

you could add this to the rules section of your eslintrc:

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": ["error",
    {
        "selector": "*:matches(ForOfStatement, ForInStatement) > VariableDeclaration.left:matches([kind=let], [kind=const])",
        "message": "let/const not allowed in lhs of for..in / for..of loops."
    },
    {
        "selector": "TemplateLiteral",
        "message": "template literal strings not allowed"
    },
    "ArrowFunctionExpression"
]
```

then, running eslint on this file

```js
for(const x of foo) {}
for(let x of foo) {}
for(const x in foo) {}
for(let x in foo) {}
console.log(`hello world`);
const bar = x => x + 1;
```

gives these errors:

```
  1:5   error  let/const not allowed in lhs of for..in / for..of loops  no-restricted-syntax
  2:5   error  let/const not allowed in lhs of for..in / for..of loops  no-restricted-syntax
  3:5   error  let/const not allowed in lhs of for..in / for..of loops  no-restricted-syntax
  4:5   error  let/const not allowed in lhs of for..in / for..of loops  no-restricted-syntax
  5:13  error  template literal strings not allowed                     no-restricted-syntax
  6:13  error  Using 'ArrowFunctionExpression' is not allowed           no-restricted-syntax

✖ 6 problems (6 errors, 0 warnings)
```

and running eslint on this file

```js
let a = 1;
const b = 2;
for(var x of foo) {}
for(var x in foo) {}
console.log('hello world');
function bar(x) { return x + 1; }
```

gives no errors

doing this for *all* es6 features would be more or less the same, just with a lot more selectors